Is free neutron decay due to "running out" of something or just by chance?
When a free neutron (as an example) decays is that due perhaps to expending energy or is it because neutrons have some internal state which changes and sometimes that change results in decay?
In the former case, all neutrons will decay within some time limit while in the latter case, there is some chance a given neutron will not have decayed for any chosen time.

It is a half-life, just like other decay half-lives.

@JonCuster: in the case of any particle which decays, just what is happening? Is an older free neutron measurably different than a newer one?

Not at all. In a given time frame there is a chance of it decaying. In the next time frame it has that same chance of decaying if it has not already.

@JonCuster: so there is no way of determining that one neutron is closer to decay than another? And yet, something must be different about them. Is it possible that some external event causes decay? I was just thinking, could collisions or temperature have an effect?

No, nothing is different. Just randomness.

@JonCuster: Hard to believe. I am not saying we can measure it, but intuitively, one neutron that is about to decay must contain some difference from one that does not end up decaying. Assuming that internal state is the determiner of decay.

That is like saying there is something different about a coin that is about to come up heads rather than tails when you flip it.

@JonCuster: the coin's internal state is not the sole determiner since the coin is flipped by an external force.
